# Insert statement yields different results than the select all in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to create a table of theater locations that only has three locations. I imported denormalized data that I tried to normalize with this statement:

```
insert into theater(`name`, email, address, phone)
select distinct theater, theater_email, theater_address, theater_phone
from denormalized_tickets;
```

when I comment out the first line and run it I get the result I'm looking for. [image: theaters normalized]

When I write a query to see the theater table `select * from theater;`, it returns the theaters duplicated each 12 times.

[image: viewing the theater table through a query]

How should I solve this? Is there anything I'm overlooking?

Comment: Did you execute the insert 12 times? Each time you execute it, that adds 3 more rows, it does not replace the existing 3 rows.

Comment: My guess is that you ran your insert statement multiple times. To avoid duplicates, create a unique index in theater table which will consist of name, email, address and phone. Also, using "limit" without "order by" is a bad practice

Comment: How many times did you run this insert statement? its going to make duplicates.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks, I didn't realize it would duplicate each time the insert statement is executed! That makes since because I just did it again and it has added three more.

Comment: @Vasya Thanks, I didn't know it would duplicate the table if I ran it more than once! I took the limit out because I was just trying to see if that would help, but that is good to know that it should be accompanied with an "order by"

Comment: @GRIV Thanks, I didn't realize it would duplicate each time the insert statement is executed. The more you know!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments above, INSERT creates new rows each time you execute it. If you do that multiple times, you may add more rows every time.

Vasya recommended creating a UNIQUE index to block new rows from being created with the same values. This may or may not be appropriate for a given table. For instance, what if you want to allow multiple rows to have the same values?

Another thing you might like to read about is MySQL's [REPLACE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html). The syntax is similar to INSERT, but if there's a duplicate in column(s) of a primary key or unique key, it first deletes the old row and then inserts the new row. But this won't help if you don't have the unique key defined, because how would MySQL know it's a conflict?